# Effectively debugging Log4j framework

Tags: java, eclipse, logging, log4j

I wanted to implement logging for my web services.I have been playing around with `Log4j`. It's a really cool logging framework when it works.But when it doesn't , it's a pain to debug.

My problem is that i am trying to log to the database , but for some reason I don't see anything being logged to the table. I have no clue whats causing this.

In my `log4j.xml` i have the following line

```
<log4j:configuration debug="true"
    xmlns:log4j='http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/'>
```

But when i deploy and run my web service in the debug mode in Eclipse , I don't see logging related debug statements on the console.

I want to be able to see

- log4j initializing and configuring the loggers. So if anything is wrong with my  xml configuration i would know immediately.
- log4j logging to the destination , in this case to the database. If there is a some kind of a sql/database exception I would know.

I am logging at the application level (the application is using its own log4j jar and configuration files as opposed to using the application servers logging mechanism)

My project uses `log4j-1.2.17` , `Eclipse Luna 4.4.0`, `JBoss EAP 6.4.0`.

Can our log4j experts suggest ways to effectively debug log4j itself. Are there Eclipse plugins that can help alleviate the pain.